# Image Deblurring by Frequency Domain Inverse Filter Design

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gaussianblur

I have a task about using a Gaussian Filter to blur an image then using the corresponding inverse Gaussian Filter to deblur the blurred image. The detailed instructions are shown below:

Apply 2D-DFT to the spatial domain Gaussian filter, resulting in a frequency domain
Gaussian filter. Create a frequency domain inverse Gaussian filter by taking the
reciprocal value of all frequency domain Gaussian filter coefficients. Apply inverse 2DDFT and take the real-parts to create a spatial domain inverse Gaussian filter (the
imaginary parts are theoretically 0, but may not be completely 0 due to numerical errors).

The size of the blurring filter is 21x21, and the size of the original image is 256x256. Here is my blurring code on Matlab.

```
Img = imread('text.tif');
img = im2double(Img);
gf = zeros(21);
for i = 1:21
    for j = 1:21
        gf(i,j) = (1/(2*pi))*exp(-((i-10.5)^2+(j-10.5)^2)/2);
    end
end
Convig = conv2(img,gf);
```

The output image is shown below.
[Blurred Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HvYO.png)

Then following the instructions, my deblurring code is shown below:

```
dftgf =fft2(gf);
idftgf = 1./dftgf;
inverse = ifft2(idftgf);
gf2 =real(inverse);
Convig2 = conv2(Convig,gf2);
```

The result of blurring seems to be correct. But it is strange that the deblurring image is incorrect [Deblurring Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX1t2.png). Could someone help me with my code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Okay finally I found the mistake.
For the formula of Guassian filter, it is said that

```
gf(i,j) = (1/(2*pi*sigma^2))*exp(-((i-center)^2+(j-center)^2)/(2*sigma^2);
```

but here I used "10.5" directly. If I use "11" as the center, the result image is correct.

So the deblurring pseudo code should be:

```
[m,n] = size(filter)
centerx = m+1/2
centery = n+1/2
gf(i,j) = (1/(2pi*sigma^2))*exp(-((i-centerx)^2+(j-centery)^2)/(2*sigma^2);
```

However, even if I found the mistake, I still do not know why it cannot be decimals. Maybe image processing is a kind of discrete programming?

Comment: Nice catch, usually the centre filter kernels has to be an integer number. During convolution, the centre pixel determines the position of the resultant. Here is a gif showing the process https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2D_Convolution_Animation.gif.

Comment: As an aside, the 11th pixel is the centre pixel since to it's left there will be 10 pixels and to it's right there will another 11 pixels.